# How to transfer url from one class to another activity

Tags: java, android

In my app urls are getting from the firebase database . I want to send these url to the another activity. how can i pass the url (Uri webpage) to the 
  viewer class.Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Why cannot you do it by `intent.putExtra('url', url)` and then `intent.getExtra('url')`?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Answer (score 0):

Use intent in first activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", value);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

And retrieve it on the second activity:

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java)

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("key",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("key1","your uri");
    editor.apply();
```

if you want get value in new ativity

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("key",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String uri=sharedPref.getString("key1","default value if value is null");
```

keys values must be same

Answer (score 0):

You can also send String Array via intent from one activity to another.

In sender's activity, you can add URL string array into intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
String[] urls = new String[] {
        "https://google.com",
        "https://stackoverflow.com"
};
intent.putExtra("urls", urls);
startActivity(intent);
```

In MainActivity (Receiver), you can get String array from intent.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] urls = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("urls");
    }
}
```

Hope it will be helpful.